# Formula to exclude rounding figure

Tags: formula-field

I want to create a basic formula to multiply one field by another.  The only issue I have is one field is a formula field that I have rounded to the nearest whole number.  However the results in the formula field still calculate the part numbers.

Example
**Wages**: $701

**Savings** (Formula 25% of Wages):175  *(decimal place = 0)*

**Weeks Savings Plan:** 20

**Total Savings**(formula Savings__c * Weeks_savings_plan__c :3505

Although the figure is correct I would like the figure to be 3500 (20*175)

I've missed something off the formula.  How do I get the formula to only use what is displayed in the box.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you storing the savings formula as a number or percent?

Comment: @MANUELAN00 - A number

Comment: Can you post your formula please?

Comment: Savings__c * Weeks_savings_plan__c    ***                                                            Savings__c is a formula field but does not display decimal places - It is rounded to the nearest whole number.

Comment: The error should be in your Savings__c, can you post that one please? Depending on the type of formula a real value is stored but is shown different...If you post the formula I can help you with that...

Comment: Wages__c * 0.25  decimal place = 0

Comment: FLOOR(Wages__c * 0.25). I will post the answer...

Comment: Glad to help buddy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update your formula Savings__c to FLOOR(Wages__c * 0.25). With this you will **show and save** the value round a number down (0).

Keep your formula **Total Savings** as it is and it should be fine.

Mark it as best answer if answered your question.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Total Savings = `ROUND( Savings__c, 0) * Weeks_savings_plan__c`

Comment: Thanks, This works also.  I'll note them both down.  Cheers